# JSF web page include

Tags: java, jsf, jstl, facelets

I am currently working on a JAVA web application using JSF, Facelets, JSTL and EL. I have 10 pages that need to include some HTML and Javascript that I have placed into a inc.jspf.

I have tried to use:

```
<jsp:include page="inc.jspf" />
```

but I am getting an error:

> The prefix "jsp" for element "jsp:include" is not bound.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks, Randall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using facelets, the `jsp:include` is logically not working - JSP and Facelets are different view technologies. You should use the following instead:

```
<ui:include src="inc.jspf" />
```